# Codeigniter 3.x PHP Background Process

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, listener, worker

I would like to know if you can and how to make a background process run when you press a button. I need this to be able to load data into a database so that the user can continue browsing the web app.

I have read that it can be done with listener and worker but I don't know how they are used with Codeigniter 3.x

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please show what you've done so far and exactly what isn't working

Comment: At the moment I have nothing done since the information I find about the worker and listener in php is scarce.

Comment: I don't need to give me the code done, with just some information and what to use is worth it

Comment: @Gricey While most of the time I would agree that showing some code is to be expected here on SO, I belive this is one of those cases where we can make an exception. Some times, the OP knows how to code and is just a little blocked by not being able to figure out "what" to do, rather than "how" to do it and is just looking for suggestions on how to approach a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do that. Which one you use will greatly depend on what your specific needs and skills are (e.g., how quickly you need the background process to finish so that it provides the output to the user, what other technologies are part of your whole app, what your skills are, etc)

I know this is not a full answer, but I'll tell you what I did when faced to a similar problem some time ago. I hope it serves as a starting point or at least as an idea.

**The problem:**

Much like yourself, I needed users to be able to post some data to my backend. Such data (not a big chunk, just 5-7 fields) when posted needed to first be stored on a table and then trigger a huge process that would take around 30 seconds to complete. During those 30 seconds, I needed the user to be able to continue using the app (as opposed to just sit there waiting for the controller to finish the 30 second process).

To make it a little bit more complex, my client had requested that upon posting, the user should remain in the current page (so no posting and then re-drawing a view in the user's browser).

**The Approach:**

1.- My client's request was fairly simple: the form would post via Ajax. Not being a great fan of complex JS libraries which are overkill for most of my projects (and being a little bit of an old-school kind of person), I just had the form be processed by a simple vanilla JS script that would take the form data, post it to my controller and upon successful response from the controller (in about 100 milliseconds), would alert the user that all was fine and let him carry on.

In order to get the fast response, the controller receiving the Ajax data needed to do just the following:

a. Run form validation (never, ever trust user input)
b. Store the form data into a table
c. Schedule the hard processing so that it would happen asynchronously. More on this in the next section

2.- The async processing was a little bit more challenging. Here's how I did it.

I created a semaphore table that referenced the form data on another table (let's call them `semaphore` and `user_posts`). The semaphore table was fairly simple: a unique ID field, a field referencing the `user_posts` unique ID where the data lived, a status field (with possible statuses `pending`, `working`, `complete`, `failed`) the insertion date and the last update date.

Next, I set up a separate controller (creatively named `Cron`) that would only work when invoked from the CLI  (the Codeigniter documentation explains how to do that) with various methods that would do the actual work. Whenever the cron daemon woke up and called the main `manager` method, that method would check the `semaphore` table for any `pending` rows and pick the oldest one. It would then hand it over to a `worker` method, that would then mark it as `working` and begin processing the data. After processing, the row would be marked as `complete` (or `failed` which would trigger other actions that I don't need to explain here) and go back to sleep.

**Some more info**

The cron daemon woke up the `manager` once every 5 minutes. Originally, when my client's app had low traffic, it was more than enough to handle the load (most of the time, the `manager` would wake up, see nothing was pending and go back to sleep). As traffic grew and the semaphore started becoming an ever-growing queue of pending items, we did some work to allow multiple instances of the `worker` to be spawned by the `manager` and run in parallel, each working on a different semaphore row. Eventually, the amount of work that was queued between each 5-minute awakening of the cron daemon became such that we needed to change the scheduling to 1-minute intervals and set up a dedicated cron server to handle the load without affecting the site's performance (remember, each dataset took around 30 seconds to process).

Well, this may not be the answer you expected (I'm behind an NDA on this, so I can't provide specific code) but as I said before, this may at least give you an idea on how to tackle this. There's many many other ways to approach this kind of problem. This is only one of them

Comment: It helps me to start. In this time I have to say that I found this plugin for Codeigniter. Which works as a JavaScript worker and listener